# CharLower() and characters wider than 16 bits

Tags: winapi, unicode

So the documentation of [`CharLower`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647467.aspx) says that it can also convert single characters, namely:

> If the high-order word of this parameter is zero, the low-order word must contain a single character to be converted.

This is confusing me because if the high-order word should be zero'ed out, this would mean that `CharLower()` can only convert characters in the range of U+0000 to U+FFFF. But what about characters in higher ranges? Would I have to convert those to an `LPTSTR` first and pass that to `CharLower()` then or how is this supposed to work?

Comment: I can't experiment right now to write a full answer, but a `wchar_t` (or `TCHAR`, i.e. `WCHAR` on Unciode) on Windows is 16-bit, which is UCS-2 legacy. To support characters with a Unicode code point over 0xFFFF or 65,535, you need to use a [surrogate pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) existing of two 16-bit characters. In other words, a string.

Comment: So there is no way to convert a 32-bit Unicode character to lower case using the Win32 API without taking the string detour?

Comment: I'm afraid so, indeed.

Comment: Well, look on the bright side.  The odds that your program *actually* ever has to case-fold text written in Deseret, Old Hungarian or Varang Kshiti ought to be pretty low.  This is only an imaginary problem.

Comment: @Andreas: 32bit characters are expressed using UTF-32, which the Win32 API does not support.  Everything is either done in 8-bit Ansi or UTF-16. So, if you have a 32bit Unicode character, convert it to UTF-16, and be sure to take surrogates into account for characters > U+FFFF.  Or use a 3rd party Unicode library that can handle UTF-32, such as [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The full quote from the documentation is as follows:

> A null-terminated string, or specifies a single character. If the high-order word of this parameter is zero, the low-order word must contain a single character to be converted.

This parameter is interpreted either as:

- a pointer to a null terminated string, or
- a single `wchar_t` value.

The reason that this is possible is that memory addresses < 65536 are reserved and considered invalid pointers. To use the function in this single character mode, you would call it like this:

```
WCHAR chr = (WCHAR) CharLowerW((WCHAR*)L'A');
```

You then ask:

> This is confusing me because if the high-order word should be zero'ed out, this would mean that `CharLower()` can only convert characters in the range of U+0000 to U+FFFF. But what about characters in higher ranges? Would I have to convert those to an `LPTSTR` first and pass that to `CharLower()` then or how is this supposed to work?

This is correct. In the single character mode, surrogate pairs are not supported. You would have to pass those as a null-terminated string instead.

It is reasonable to guess that this interface dates back to the days when Windows supported UCS-2, a pre-cursor to UTF-16. UCS-2 was a fixed length encoding that only supported codepoints <= U+FFFF, and the problems that you describe did not arise. UTF-16 added surrogates for codepoints > U+FFFF. This interface design is comprehensive, albeit somewhat clunky.